# Какой есть аналог COUNT(DISTINCT) в ms-acces?

Tags: sql, запрос, ms-access

Нужно вывести список экскурсий с указанием количества посещаемых залов

Схема данных такая:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается сделать так, чтобы считал правильно, т.е. если один зал посещался дважды, то считался только один.

**Обновление**

```
SELECT Экскурсии.[Тема экскурсии], COUNT([Залы галереи].[Номер зала]) AS [Count-Номер зала]
FROM [Залы галереи] INNER JOIN (Картины INNER JOIN (Экскурсии INNER JOIN [Содержание экскурсий] ON Экскурсии.[Код экскурсии] = [Содержание экскурсий].[Код экскурсии]) ON Картины.[Код картины] = [Содержание экскурсий].[Код картины]) ON [Залы галереи].[Номер зала] = Картины.[Номер зала]
GROUP BY Экскурсии.[Тема экскурсии];
```

Comment: свой бы запрос написали что ли ... подозреваю что в нем надо будет обычный count заменить на `count(distinct зал)`

Comment: И что, неужели count(distinct Номерзала) не дал нужного результата ?

Comment: @Mike, могу ошибаться, но access вроде бы не поддерживает `count(distinct ...)`.

Comment: @Arrsenal, свой код лучше добавлять в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Comment: @i-one Да, вижу. Мне в голову не приходило что нечто SQL совместимое может это не поддерживать. рекомендуют жуткий изврат ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Тема экскурсии], COUNT([Номер зала]) AS [Count-Номер зала]
FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT Экскурсии.[Тема экскурсии], [Залы галереи].[Номер зала]
  FROM [Залы галереи] INNER JOIN (Картины INNER JOIN (Экскурсии INNER JOIN   [Содержание экскурсий] ON Экскурсии.[Код экскурсии] = [Содержание экскурсий].[Код экскурсии]) ON Картины.[Код картины] = [Содержание экскурсий].[Код картины]) ON [Залы галереи].[Номер зала] = Картины.[Номер зала]
)as T
GROUP BY [Тема экскурсии]
```